# Why can I run my program after cleaning in Eclipse and Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I cannot understand why  in `Eclipse` after these two steps

1. `Run as` -> `Maven clean`
2. `Project` -> `clean...`

I can still run my program using green icon with white arrow?

I thought there are no `.class` files after cleaning. I was expecting exception like `ClassNotFound`, but nothing like this happened.

Do you know how to properly clean project in `Eclipse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked this phenomenon out with one of my `Maven` projects in `Eclipse` and this is what I observed. By the way, don't trust what you see in the `Package View`, use your file system explorer.

Run as -> Maven clean : deletes the target folder
Project -> clean... : creates `target` folder with empty subfolders "`classes`" and "`test-classes`". In `Eclipse's` `Package Explorer` view, I see an empty target folder.

At this point I would say the proper way to clean a `Maven` project in `Eclipse` is simply to do Run as -> `Maven` clean.

Now to address why your program runs after cleaning. As soon as I ran a program in the project, `Eclipse` compiled and populated the "`target/classes`" and "`target/test-classes`" folders with *.class files and resources. In `Eclipse's` `Package Explorer` view, I still see an empty target folder.

The trick to figuring this out was to look at the project directory and sub directories with the system file explorer and not just with `Eclipse's` `Package View` or `Project View`.

Answer (score 3):

Clean in eclipse is not the same as clean in maven.
Maven's clean indeed removes all compiled resources (classes etc). 
Clean project in eclipse is a kind of `mvn clean compile`, i.e. it removes `*class` files and compiles all `*.java` files again.

Comment: but when I do cleaning I don't select `Start a build immediately`. Also I don't use `Project` -> `Build automatically`. What else should I do?

Comment: @trebuchet First, when do `Project` -> `clean`, the .class file will been removed. Please check `bin` folder of your project to make sure this. Then you run your program, this operation will build the project automatically if eclipse found your project does not build yet.

Answer (score 1):

In starting code for your application you can add:

```
System.out.println("Classpath=" + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

you can analyze it (nornally I use notepaddpp to split it by classpath separator and sort) - maybe it refers to jars in maven repo which contains classes as well? Sometime class folders are first on classpath and thus are before jars even if in jars there are the same classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because eclipse will auto build your project when you run it

Comment: I don't use `Project` -> `Build automatically`. Is there another option?

Comment: You can check the other answer for a better explanation